# How to handle channel closing synchronisation in case of slow producer, fast consumer in go?

Tags: go, channel, producer-consumer

I am new to go, and couldn't find an answer to this problem. What I am doing, is to read a CSV file in producer, doing some stuff which may take time, and then sending the output to a consumer via a channel. There's a chain of **producer-consumer**s, and any producer may end up being slower than it's consumer.

> producer(1 goroutine) -> chan0 -> consumer-producer-1(>1 goroutines) -> chan1 ->
>   consumer-producer-2(>1 goroutines) -> chan2 -> consumer(>1 goroutines)

There can be up to 15 consumers here.

Now the problem that I face is how to decide on the consumer side if the producer is done, and we can stop processing.

What I need to achieve is:

1. once producer is done, all consumers should eventually do some cleanup and exit after finishing the remaining
2. If a consumer doesn't get any data for a specific timeout period, it can exit(with a signal, preferably) without blocking any further.
3. It happens for all the producer-consumer pair across the sequence.

I have used the following approach.

1. To keep a signal channel along with each data channel, and to publish a "done", for each goroutine of its next consumer.
2. After reading it, each consumer should just read the remaining buffered data in the channel and then put, say 5 "done" on next signal channel. Ensuring that it's only 5, and not 5 for each goroutine (using https://golang.org/pkg/sync/#Once.Do).
3. Below is what I could think of till here.

   ```
   processRemaining = false
   for processRemaining == false{
           select {
           case stuff, ok := <-input_messages:
                   do_stuff(stuff)
                   if ok == false { // if channel has been closed
                       processRemaining = true
                   }
                   if result != nil {
                           //send to channel output_messages
                   }
           case sig := <-input_signals: // if signaled to stopped.
                   fmt.Println("received signal", sig)
                   processRemaining = true
           default:
                   fmt.Println("no activity")
           }
   }
   if processRemaining {
           for stuff := range input_messages {
                   do_stuff(stuff)
                   if result != nil {
                           //send to channel output_messages
                   }
           }
           // send "output_routine" number of "done" to a channel "output_signals".
   }
   ```

But even in this approach, I am unable to think of any way to behave the same way as closed "input_messages" channel, if nothing is available for, say 10 seconds.

Are there any problems I am ignoring with this approach. What are the possible way (or concurrency patterns) to approach this problem? ensuring:

1. All the subsequent channels are closed, once first "chan0" is closed.
2. All the producers are updated before closing their output channel, and the channel is closed only once they all have finished their writes.
3. If a consumer gets no data from a channel for a specified timeout, it should treat it as closed, and unblocks itself.

Comment: I couldn't understand why my question has been down-voted. Can you please point out what do I need to improve?

Comment: I didn't downvote but your question is too big to answer, maybe you can break it into parts and then ask what's required.

Comment: Don't know, have seen much larger questions on SO. Anyways, I removed a few parts that could be ignored. Remaining content seems necessary for someone to be able to understand the problem. Feel free to suggest an edit.

Comment: idiomatic go, is not to send data through channels, but send references. i.e., >Do not communicate by sharing memory; instead, share memory by communicating.

Comment: Great, another downvote. It would have been much better if people downvoting could also tell what they disliked so much. I have searched enough to make sure that it's not a duplicate on SO. I haven't asked any homework sort of question, and have done initial brain-storming. If still, there's something that doesn't fit, it would be helpful to call it out.

Comment: @nilsocket : In my case, I am sharing small maps of the csv data. Much lesser than 64 kb in size. I am not sharing references to avoid any risk of race conditions. But how does using references help with syncronising closing of channels, and avoiding blocking/write after close here?

Comment: nope, it have nothing to do with mentioned problem, it's not idiomatic that's it.

Comment: What is that you actually wanted do(what do you intend to achieve)?, why chain of producers and consumers?

Comment: I thought you could see this but your question will soon be closed for this reason: Primarily Opinion Based. Many good questions generate some degree of opinion based on expert experience, but answers to this question will tend to be almost entirely based on opinions, rather than facts, references, or specific expertise.

Comment: @nilsocket, it's perfectly normal to send non-pointer values down a channel. It's no different from passing values to functions in this regard. You do whatever makes sense in any given case.

Comment: @nilsocket : There's a graph representing dependencies in a system. It is topologically sorted. Each node has to do its own operation after the previous node is done. But once the data is available, there are no dependencies among the nodes (hence, they can run concurrently). Each node's operations have different "load", so they are free to create a different number of go-routines.

Comment: It seems kind of complicated to me. But there were other concurrency patterns, which may help you in `x/sync` repository for an introduction you can look over [here](https://rodaine.com/2018/08/x-files-sync-golang/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a `sync.WaitGroup` to keep track of the number of running goroutines. Each goroutine exits after it no longer gets data from the channel. Once the `WaitGroup` is done, the cleanup can be done.

Something like this:

```
import (
        "sync"
        "time"
)

type Data interface{} // just an example

type Consumer interface {
        Consume(Data) Data
        CleanUp()
        Count() int
        Timeout() time.Duration
}

func StartConsumers(consumer Consumer, inCh <-chan Data, outCh chan<- Data) {
        wg := sync.WaitGroup{}
        for i := 0; i < consumer.Count(); i++ {
                wg.Add(1)
                go func() {
                consumeLoop:
                        for {
                                select {
                                case v, ok := <-inCh: // 'ok' says if the channel is still open
                                        if !ok {
                                                break consumeLoop
                                        }
                                        outCh <- consumer.Consume(v)
                                case <-time.After(consumer.Timeout()):
                                        break consumeLoop
                                }
                        }

                        wg.Done()
                }()
        }
        wg.Wait()

        consumer.CleanUp()
        close(outCh)
}
```

At each stage of the pipeline, you can use a similar process as the above to start the consumers.

Comment: a context seems appropriate. Also I dont quiet understand why there is a GOTO statement to restart the loop. The time.After select case would return to the beginning of the loop, producing same effect with more idiomatic code.

Comment: @mh-cbon I believe OP wants a timeout for one channel read and not the whole operation, so a context probably doesn’t help here. Also there’s no goto. Are you referring to the break?

Comment: Thanks for the answer. In my case, my goroutines have a call to wg.Done() with defer, and I am using a cleanup similar to what you suggested, where I close the output channel, so that other consumers in the pipeline may also get the hint that no more data is coming. It also ensures that no writes happen after closing the channel. But yes, it's not a very clean implementation (using an interface, for instance). That surely is my take away from your answer.

Comment: But what I am stuck with is to decide when to stop processing these goroutines. For example, deciding if the channel has been closed by the producer, or there is a delay in data availability. "for range" is blocking in both cases, and "for {}"(infinite) needs to have clear indication to break out of loop.

Another thing, I don't want to solely rely on either input channel being closed, or signal. In case, there's some unexpected issue at producer, I want consumers to go ahead and exit if there is no data for a timeout duration.

Comment: @mh-cbon : I have updated the code. The "break" in my code was useless. I actually use a flag that controls the for loop. Didn't know same can be done using a label with break.
Below seems to solve my problem.
case <-time.After(consumer.Timeout()):
                                        break consumeLoop

Comment: @Tushar the range loop finishes when the channel is closed by the producer. There’s a timeout check inside the select which breaks out of the loop - based on what I understand you need.

Comment: Yes, thanks a lot. It solves my problem.

Comment: @svsd : Any suggestion on how to ensure that I close the output channel(outCh) only after ensuring all the consumer goroutines have stopped writing to it (as the consumers are also writing to the input channel of the next node) ?

Comment: @Tushar The WaitGroup is already used to ensure that no more consumers are running before things are cleaned up.

Comment: @svsd : I have recently started a small open source project with this use case. Still in a very initial stage.
Would love to have your feedback someday, if you can find some time.
Your inputs helped in setting up initial building blocks.
https://github.com/tushar2708/conveyor